# Find content in specific DIV with Behat/Selenium

Tags: php, html, xpath, behat, mink

I am creating a Behat/Selenium automated test script.  I want to create a statement that says:

```
Given I am on "/"
Then I should see <CONTENT> in <SPECIFIC DIV>
```

I want to create a function in my FeatureContext.php file that will allow me to verify content (text) exists only within a specified DIV tag.  Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Sounds like you need to use a regex?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be pointed in the right direction, then you should avoid doing things as such – they contradict with Behat ideology. Your scenario describes actions the user performs and assertions that he makes to verify the result as a user who looks at the page, not as a developer who looks into the code. The logic of the last must be done by you behind the scenes. In other words, your step should read more like this:

```
Given I am on the homepage
Then the page title should read "hello world"
And the user list should contain "john doe"
And the dialogue title should be "foo bar"
```

If you want the answer to the initial question, then you can do it as such:

```
/**
 * @Then /^(?:|I )should see "(?P<text>.+)" in the "(?P<selector>\w+)" element$/
 */
public function assertElementText($text, $selector) {
    $page    = $this->getSession()->getPage();
    $element = $page->findAll('css', $selector);

    foreach($this->getSession()->getPage()->findAll() as $element) {
        if (strpos(strtolower($text), strtolower($element->getText()) !== false) {
            return;
        }
    }

    throw Exception("Text '{$text}' is not found in the '{$selector}' element.");
}
```

And use it like this:

```
Then I should see "hello world" in the "div#title" element
Then I should see "john doe" in the "ul#users > li" element
```

Comment: Thanks Ian.  I know I am delayed with the reply.  But your solution, once again, worked and got me to where I needed to be with my testing at work.  Thanks again. Something tells me this will not be the last time we correspond, lol.